# Unable to add multiple parameters to task when deployed via a stream in spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a task which takes 3 different parameters to run it's batch jobs. When running from UI i pass them as task arguments and it works. Now I am trying to create a stream which deploys the task with these parameters every 5 mins. I'm using the triggertask source and task-launcher-local sink for this.
The following stream definition is giving me an error and not adding the stream:

```
triggertask --environment-properties=appnexus_seat=SEAT_MIQ_1,last_modified=2018/08/03,start_element=0 --uri=file:///home/MIQDIGITAL/siddhant/scdf-tasks/spring-cloud-task-aiq-batch-module/aiq-appnexus-batch-service/target/aiq-appnexus-batch-service-3.23.1.jar --time-unit=MINUTES | task-launcher-local
```

Error:

```
Caught exception while handling a request: 100E:(pos 75): Found unexpected data after stream definition: '='
triggertask --environment-properties=appnexus_seat=SEAT_MIQ_1,last_modified=2018/08/03,start_element=0 --uri=file:///home/MIQDIGITAL/siddhant/scdf-tasks/spring-cloud-task-aiq-batch-module/aiq-appnexus-batch-service/target/aiq-appnexus-batch-service-3.23.1.jar --time-unit=MINUTES --fixed-delay=2 | task-launcher-local
```

Then when i add them as command-line-args I get the same error:

```
triggertask --uri=file:///home/MIQDIGITAL/siddhant/scdf-tasks/spring-cloud-task-aiq-batch-module/aiq-appnexus-batch-service/target/aiq-appnexus-batch-service-3.23.1.jar --time-unit=MINUTES --fixed-delay=2 --command-line-args=appnexus_seat=SEAT_MIQ_1,last_modified=2018/08/03,start_element=0 | task-launcher-local
```

But when i run the same with only one command line argument it run perfectly:

```
triggertask --uri=file:///home/MIQDIGITAL/siddhant/scdf-tasks/spring-cloud-task-aiq-batch-module/aiq-appnexus-batch-service/target/aiq-appnexus-batch-service-3.23.1.jar --time-unit=MINUTES --fixed-delay=2 --command-line-args=appnexus_seat=SEAT_MIQ_1 | task-launcher-local
```

**So the issue is with passing multiple arguments. How can i do that?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/2451#issuecomment-425974434](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2451#issuecomment-425974434).